# Firefox does not make resource request

Tags: firefox

I'm trying both chrome and Firefox, for one resource, Firefox does not make request to get it after downloading it once (I'm actually upgrading it), and firebug shows this line in response header

```
The request was resolved directly from the cache, so we have no response from the server. See below for the cached response.
```

However, chrome works fine.  Is this a firefox bug or something?

The first download request in firebug
[image: The first download request in firebug]

Comment: Try to clear your FF cache

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34243073/1641556