# The resource at "http://some-urls/some-files.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled

Tags: firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk

I got this error in `javascript` console while using the **Facebook Login Api**.

```
The resource at "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.


 // Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

**Google + plugin also blocked,Now my Facebook like and other social network plugins not work on Firefox 42.0**

I used Firefox 42.0

Comment: I think this is a security feature of the Firefox new version.

Comment: So, how you fix this issue? I'm facing the same issue, can you please help?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @MahaDev  Still there's no solution with Firefox 42.0

Comment: I have the same issue check link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218271/facebook-like-button-is-not-displaying-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment56180977_34218271

And the web console is also giving me same error.

Comment: even posting 300 total bounty didnt help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294989/impossible-to-use-a-twitter-timeline-in-firefox/34546547?noredirect=1#comment56834666_34546547

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature call **Firefox Tracking Protection.**

> Tracking Protection allows Firefox users to avoid many forms of online
>   tracking. Originally based on the blocklist from antitracking startup
>   Disconnect, the feature offers better privacy while also speeding up
>   page loads by blocking requests to tracking domains.

**How to turn Off Tracking Protection**

- In the Firefox Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.

*The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the about:config page.*

- Search for privacy.trackingprotection.enabled.
- Double-click `privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` to set its value
  to `false`.

**This will turn off Tracking Protection. If you later want to turn it back on, repeat the above steps to toggle the preference back to false.**

[image]