# Firefox blocking Facebook Js

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox

with upgrade of Firefox to 42.0 I got some strange behavior..

I'm calling FB.init method like this:

```
FB.init({ 
        appId: '{$appid}',
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
```

But in Firefox it gets blocked, I get warning:

**The resource at "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.**

This is default behavior, I didn't set up any additional security or whatever..

What to do?

**EDIT - after help and googling, this is a little bigger problem:**

Turns out Firefox's Do Not Track and **tracking protection** are two separate things:

**Do Not Track** is enabled in Preferences/Options > Privacy > "Tell sites that I do not want to be tracked". Enabling sends the DNT header but it does not block any requests.

**Tracking Protection** is enabled in about:config > privacy.trackingprotection.enabled. Enabling does not send the DNT header, but does block requests based on Disconnect's blocklist. So detecting 2 isn't as easy as checking navigator.doNotTrack, because that property is only set for 1.

Solution (temporarily) - try to do FB.init, if error do some alert..

```
try {
        FB.init({ 
            appId: '{$appid}',
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
    }catch(err) {
        alert('Some info for the user...');
    }
```

Does anyone have better solution?

Comment: Is this occuring in a `Private Browsing window`?

Comment: On my Firefox 42.0 it works. It might be one of your issues...

Comment: Hi, how have you fixed this issue? I mean, the solution can't be just go in the about:config because the system's user will not do that...

Comment: hi, its based on client setup..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the client side, you can't. This is security policy Firefox. You can read about this issue in thread: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226498

Answer (score 7):

A simple google search leads to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection

You should be able to deactivate that feature right where the message appears, or via `about:config`. It should actually be deactivated by default afaik.

Comment: Thank you.. Since i need FB methods for login, how do I deactivate this tracking protection automatically? Via javascript instead of users?

Comment: it would be weird if it would be possible to deactivate this automatically, dont you think? it would make the whole point of tracking protection pointless...since it should not be activated by default, there should be no problem though.

Comment: Yes, i agree with this, but your comment made me think this is possible. Since i cant ask user to do this there is no way to use Facebook login - that's like URGh...

Comment: Well, I just upgraded Firefox, and it is ON by default (at least for me). And I'm sure many users will just keep it that way. It would be nice to detect this with javascript and give user warning.. I tried "navigator.doNotTrack", but this does not work since this is tracking protection! Still looking for solution to at least detect the "tracking protection"

Comment: well...upgrading firefox keeps your settings, no surprise there.

Comment: I also done the same thing and it's works for me answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34243073/1641556

Comment: Sometimes the thrid party content is blocked by the corporate IT in Firefox config

Answer (score 0):

If any one is coming to this post to find how to handle this error. I think this answer may help.

```
            (function (d, s, id) {
                let js,
                    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);

//here goes the error handling 
                js.onerror = (e) => {
                    //here we can handle the error
                    //we can show the user why the page isn't loading correctly
                }

                js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

Answer (score -1):

A way to go about it is checking whether the FB object exists after all script resources have been loaded. In this way we are covered regardless of what caused the script load failure:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    // If Facebook SDK failed to load ... 
    if (typeof FB === "undefined") {

         // ... then change interface/set global variable to handle missing FB

    }

});
```