# Facebook like button is not displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a page and I open it in a fancybox. It is working fine in chrome and it's private mode too. 
It is working in Firefox but it is not working when I opened the private browsing.

The URL of site is: [Facebook like btn issue in firefox incognito](http://ecom.sofizar.com/)

Please help me to get rid of that problem.

Comment: Newer versions of Firefox Private Browsing have privacy-centric content blocking. Perhaps this is the reason?

Comment: In Firefox and in Web console, there is a warning when private browsing as
Warning: The resource at "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.

For this, I check the button in settings for firefox for tracking but I still did not find the solution.

Comment: This is Firefox security feature.They did not accept `Cross-domain Content Scripts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[firefox-42-brings-tracking-protection-to-private-browsing](http://www.zdnet.com/article/firefox-42-brings-tracking-protection-to-private-browsing/)

[firefox-tracking-protection-decreases-page-load-times-by-44](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/05/24/firefox-tracking-protection-decreases-page-load-times-by-44/)

Please see the above links, it clearly mentioned that the ads, analytics trackers, and social share buttons are blocked preventing page loading issues in the browser. As sites may depend on these scripts and may refuse to load fully or partially. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243073/1641556

> How to turn Off Tracking Protection
>
> ```
> In the Firefox Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
> ```
>
> The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may
>   appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the
>   about:config page.
>
> ```
> Search for privacy.trackingprotection.enabled.
>
> Double-click privacy.trackingprotection.enabled to set its value to false.
> ```

Comment: We cant add this in each browser. Or tell the users to do it.