# Impossible to use a twitter timeline in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, twitter

When I try to use a twitter timeline, or view a twitter timeline on any site in Firefox I am greeted with the console warning:

```
The resource at "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.
```

I have three parts to this question:

1. **Why is firefox blocking twitter timelines/widgets?**
2. **What can I do to make the timeline show?**

and the most infuriating:

3. **Why is this happening even though tracking protection is NOT enabled???**

Here are some examples of timelines that get blocked:

http://www.success-equation.com/home.html
http://userapp-io.github.io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/demo/demo.html
http://entrepreneurship101.mit.edu/ (in the footer)
http://minitwitter.webdevdesigner.com/

Here is an example that works (only on twitter.com domain)
https://blog.twitter.com/2014/3-power-tips-for-using-embedded-timelines

Here is an explanation of tracking protection on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243073/3700836

and last, but not least, proof that it is actually disabled:
[image]

*Firefox 42.0 - Mac OSX 10.10, also seen on Windows 10*

---

An amusing but frustrating footnote: Don't bother tweeting to Twitter @support, they don't respond to tweets.

Comment: What happens when you go directly to https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js in Firefox?

Comment: @xkcd149 it loads the js file. Also the example timeline on the twitter developer site, as the js file comes from the same root domain (my understanding). Any other sites twitter timeline widget does not load.

Comment: What happens if you change the JQuery loader to use https?

Comment: @AdamKatz I changed `p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';` to `p='https'`. No luck - the error just changed to use https.

Comment: @DavidAnderton well it worked for me when I forked your repo.  Here's [my functional fork](https://adamhotep.github.io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/demo/demo.html). (I've got privacy.trackingprotection.enabled=false and services.sync…trackingprotection.enabled=true on Firefox 42.0 on Linux)

Comment: @AdamKatz So I assume it also works with that repo without changing it to `p='https'`? Perhaps this is just an issue with Windows/ OSX Firefox... I've not tried on linux as of yet. Also if not clear your functional fork works on my chrome, but not on firefox, same error with https url

Comment: Where does `p` come from?  I merely edited the HTML (see [diff](https://github.com/adamhotep/twitter-timeline-angularjs/commit/4bc0f1d227f1ab838758cd275a46c17b36313ebc)) to use the SSL version of the JQuery source code.  I've also now [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/userapp-io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/pull/4) to fix that in the userapp-io repo.

Comment: @AdamKatz apologies, the p is from the standard twitter timeline init (for the general case). that particular line ends up in the angular repo on line 46 of twitter-timeline.js in the `$.getScript` call

Comment: @DavidAnderton - I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294989/impossible-to-use-a-twitter-timeline-in-firefox/#34347620) since this solution works for me.  Please verify that it works for you or else refine your question to elaborate on what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98296/discussion-between-adam-katz-and-david-anderton).

Comment: @AdamKatz added some other cases to the question to show that its a broader issue than the one example i gave first of all.

Comment: Okay, I can't reproduce your issue then.  As I mentioned in chat, if you're using Ghostery, you have to enable the "Twitter Button."  You should also check to see if a shield icon appears on the left side of your location bar.  If it does, click it and disable Tracking Protection (perhaps this would work better than manually adjusting `about:config`).

Comment: As a Firefox user I deliberately chose to cripple the internet I see and get rid of 3rd party content off some sites. So I am not worried at all if a Twitter timeline does not appear on a website that is not Twitter itself.

Comment: @wigy totally respectable understand that, however I feel you should have the option to enable and disable these features and that, as far as I can see is what the options I've been looking at are. It's kind of like having Adblock stuck on - sometimes you may actually want to disable it (even though there are very few times this is the case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243073/1641556

My Settings :[image]

Current browser version : 43.0.1 (also work with 42.0)

In my web browser this (http://www.success-equation.com/home.html) works fine.

**EDIT :**
In my office pc Firefox 43.0.3 updated and that twitter plugin not work correctly.
Then I was made change with this line and ***it's worked for me***.

`privacy.trackingprotection.pbmode.enabled` `false`

[image]

Comment: Are these the default settings? I've tried these and no luck :( so your issue just seemed to resolve itself (from the other question)

Comment: Yes this is default for 43.0 but in firefox 42 I changed  `trackingprotection` for facebook plugin and it's work at that time.

Comment: I decided to not let another bounty disappear into the ether. Your answer is not the full solution, but your response to this, and your other question on this matter are clearly bringing us closer to figuring this out. thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @DavidAnderton What about the status on this issue ?

Comment: @DavidAnderton I'll check this issue and it's happen in my office pc (Firefox 43.0.3). Then I was make a change with this line and it's work charm. `privacy.trackingprotection.pbmode.enabled` `false`

Comment: excellent that fixed it. The problem remains that this is a default setting!! Makes zero sense. So the answer is that currently you cannot reliably implement a twitter timeline widget. I'm going to have to build my own from scratch with realtime updates. gah! I've marked your answer as correct as I can now load timelines, but I will reset to the browsers default behaviour as I need to test things as average joe who doesn't alter config settings. Thanks again. Glad you got the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be blocked due to depending on unencrypted content delivered through an otherwise encrypted connection.  This is because the unencrypted connection could potentially leak information.  I don't think this is related to the [Tracking Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection) feature introduced in Firefox 42.0.

I forked that repository and [changed](https://github.com/adamhotep/twitter-timeline-angularjs/commit/4bc0f1d227f1ab838758cd275a46c17b36313ebc) one character on this one line of code in the HTML:

[original (broken) version](http://userapp-io.github.io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/demo/demo.html):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

[new (functional) version](https://adamhotep.github.io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/demo/demo.html) (which will not exist forever):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

With Firefox `about:config` item `privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` set to `false`, my fork works while the original does not.  With it set to `true`, neither works.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/userapp-io/twitter-timeline-angularjs/pull/4) to get my one character change merged to the original repository.  I'll eventually kill off my fork.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but it is a general case for me independent of the implementation of the timeline. Your alteration covers one specific case, and as I mentioned in the comments unfortunately doesn't resolve the issue when i try to validate it in Windows and OSX firefox. I assume there must be some difference in the implementation of linux ff tracking protection

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example URLs that you have given and Twitter timeline works on all those pages without any issue. (FF 42.0 Win 7). And in fact I've `services.sync.prefs.sync.privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` set to true (default value).

Do you have any Add-on that might be blocking twitter timeline (may be cross origin requests)?
Try disabling all Add-Ons and check if it works for you.

Comment: It seems most ffs hit the issue but a few do not. Trying to understand the behaviour. Also it's a clean ff, no addons. I assume from the upvotes others have noted the behaviour, or maybe people just upvote bounty :)

Comment: Its FF42.0 & OS Win 7. Btw I've network.http.referer.XOriginPolicy set to 0. Is it same for you?

Comment: Not sure if it will make any difference, but I forgot to mention that I'm using a portable version of FF (http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2042.0/). Do you want to give it a try?